# adsense - any guidance on how much I could make

Tags: adsense

Does anyone know any resources where I can have some examples of how much money do some small websites make using Adsense. I haven't used adsense before and I don't know if it pays off placing adds on my webite and irritating some users.

I know I should only ask about programing, but this is the best place I could get a great answer which is something I haven't found anywhere else! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is going to vary depending on the number of visitors to your site and how many of them click on an ad.

I know the owner of a site that uses it and he breaks around $50 a month (if he is lucky).  But his site is a small blog focused on owners of a particular car. Depending on the number of visitors you have and their tendencies the amount generated can be higher or lower.

Also you can help make the ads less annoying and more relevant by targeting the ads to categories relating to your users.

Answer (score 0):

AdSense income depends primarily on three things:

- The traffic your sites get
- How many of your visitors click on the ads (CTR — clickthrough rate)
- The average per-click value of the ads

It's hard to generalize this because these three things can vary so much from site to site. That said, the best advice I can give is to spend most of your time working on getting **more traffic** to your sites. You can't do much about the per-click values (it depends mostly on your topic choice, which for established sites you've already done) or the CTR (you can tweak the placement of your ads, but the changes tend to be more incremental), but you can definitely work on getting more traffic. 10 times the traffic will normally mean 10 times the money, 100 times the traffic yields 100 times the money, etc.

$50/month is not unusual for a small site with little traffic, to be honest.